# How can we dynamically add new attributes to JPA entity classes in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We are exploring the possibility of dynamically adding attributes to an entity class. The current development stack is Spring Boot using JPA and Hibernate. The idea is to allow feeding in data using web services. The web service would allow adding new attributes to an entity class. Ideally, the new attributes should enforce or support type information.

One possible approach is to embed a map in an entity class. However, the map would store keys and values as String objects. We need to support Integer, Float, Date, and String.

We also explored storing data in a list that has objects of a custom type DataElement (String key, String value, String type). This list will be persisted in the database. Then, we generate a DynaBean from this list to access the appropriate data elements with data types enforced.

We are open to consider any approach or framework that would support this functionality. We are also open to consider other JVM languages like Groovy, Kotlin or Scala.

Answer (score 1):

In JPA , entity classes represent the persistent data model of your application. By default, entity classes are defined with a fixed set of attributes that map to database columns. However, if you need to dynamically add new attributes to entity classes at runtime, you can follow a few approaches in Spring Boot.

Using a Map: One way to handle dynamic attributes is by using a Map field in your entity class. You can define a Map<String, Object> field to store the dynamic attributes, where the keys represent the attribute names and the values are the attribute values. This approach allows you to add new attributes without changing the entity class's structure. However, keep in mind that querying and indexing dynamic attributes can be more challenging with this approach.
Here's an example of how you can use a Map for dynamic attributes in an entity class:

```
@Entity
public class DynamicEntity {
@Id
private Long id;

@ElementCollection
  private Map<String, Object> 
  dynamicAttributes = new HashMap<>();

  // getters and setters
```

}

Using JSON Serialization: Another approach is to store dynamic attributes as JSON data in a string field within the entity class. You can use libraries like Jackson to serialize and deserialize the dynamic attributes to JSON. This approach allows you to store the dynamic attributes in a structured format while still maintaining flexibility.

Here's an example of using JSON serialization for dynamic attributes:

```
@Entity
public class DynamicEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String dynamicAttributesJson;

    // getters and setters

    @Transient
    public Map<String, Object> getDynamicAttributes() {
        if (dynamicAttributesJson == null) {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.readValue(dynamicAttributesJson, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }

        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Transient
    public void setDynamicAttributes(Map<String, Object> dynamicAttributes) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            this.dynamicAttributesJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(dynamicAttributes);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach, you can use the `dynamicAttributes` field as a transient field, which means it will not be persisted in the database. Instead, it will use the dynamicAttributesJson field for persistence.

These are a couple of approaches to handle dynamic attributes in JPA entity classes in Spring Boot. Choose the one that best fits your requirements and consider the trade-offs between flexibility and queryability.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JSON as column type. Some databases can access JSON attributes in a query. When database doesn't support it you can still store a string with serialized JSON and deserialize after reading.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. We will explore this approach.